# Boto3 script to query S3 bucket file dates is slow

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-s3, boto3

I've written a simple script to find the latest file in S3 buckets. It works correctly but is extremely slow. Obviously it has a lot of files to check but if I use something like [S3 Browser](http://s3browser.com/) the file information appears almost immediately. Have I done something wrong or is this just a limitation of [bobo3](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-python/)?

```
#! /usr/bin/python3

import argparse
import boto3
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timezone

def build_argparser():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='List S3 buckets by file date.')
    parser.add_argument('-p', '--profile', help='Profile to use')
    return parser

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = build_argparser()
    args = parser.parse_args()

    if args.profile == None:
        s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
    else:
        profile = boto3.session.Session(profile_name=args.profile)
        s3 = profile.resource('s3')

    for bucket in s3.buckets.all():
        print(bucket.name)
        latest_key = ""
        latest_datetime = datetime
        for object in bucket.objects.all():
            #print('\t' + str(object.key) + ': ' + str(object.last_modified))
            if latest_datetime == datetime or latest_datetime < object.last_modified:
                latest_key = object.key
                latest_datetime = object.last_modified

        print('\t' + str(latest_key) + ': ' + str(latest_datetime))
```

Comment: How long is "extremely slow"? How many objects are in your bucket? What is your use-case? If you only need this once per day or less, you could consider using [Amazon S3 Inventory](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/storage-inventory.html) rather than doing it yourself.

Comment: Slow as in it's been running for over a day. It varies. Just want to find when each bucket was last written to, don't expect to run this regularly.

Comment: Okay, that definitely _is_ slow! I ran your code and found the time is consumed by `bucket.objects.all()`, especially if there are lots of objects in the bucket (eg hundreds or more). If you have lots of objects, I would suggest using Amazon S3 Inventory to grab the data for you.